# Chrome 57 big font size

Tags: google-chrome

when I updated google chrome to ver 57.
my menu font size , tabs font size and bookbar font size are very large.
and I can't change this.
My ubuntu version is 16.04 LTS.
I want to decrease font size but I can't.

Comment: I have the same problem and I switched back to firefox. Only problem for me was that firefox requires pulseaudio which gave me nothing but trouble some time ago and got uninstalled for good. I had to use "apulse" to fool firefox. However, in Ubuntu, using pulseaudio should be acceptable.